# How to make sure that several processes has started using pool

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

in the below code, in postTasksForNSegments() method, i am creating a process in a pool for each iteration. to confirm that there are several process started in every iteration i placed the print-statement
`print(f".current_process:{multiprocessing.current_process}")`

At run-time, i received the below posted output for the print-statement.
Given the memory address as stated below which is `0x0000017F7A4F1D80`, does that mean i did not start several processes and it is only one process started?

please let me know why i am getting the same memory address every time?
please tell me how to make sure that i did start several process in a pool?

if the code below indicates that it is only one process started, please let me know how to modify the code to start several processes

**code**:

```
@staticmethod
def initPool():
    DebugGridCellsProcessingPerNRowsUsingPool.pool = Pool(cpu_count() -1)

@staticmethod
def closePool():
    DebugGridCellsProcessingPerNRowsUsingPool.pool.close()
    DebugGridCellsProcessingPerNRowsUsingPool.pool.join()   

def postTasksForNSegments(self):
    for i in range (0,self.numOfRows):
        self.res = DebugGridCellsProcessingPerNRowsUsingPool.pool.map_async(self.run,[[
        tasksCarierForRowsOfGridCellsClassifications,
        tasksCarierForRowsOfNDVIsTIFFDetails,
        tasksCarierForRowsOfPixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt,
        tasksCarierForRowsOfPixelsValuesDoNotSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDatasetCnt,
        tasksCarierForRowsOfpixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInMixedNZCAndZCCnt,
        ....
        ....
        ....
        tasksCarierForRowsOfPixelsValuesOfNoDataInNoDataCell,
        ]],
        chunksize=self.numOfRows // cpu_count()
        )
        DebugGridCellsProcessingPerNRowsUsingPool.procs.append(self.res)
        print(f".current_process:{multiprocessing.current_process}")
```

**output of print-statement in the above code**

```
numOfRows:30
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
numOfRows:27
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
numOfRows:24
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
numOfRows:21
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
numOfRows:18
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
numOfRows:15
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
numOfRows:12
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
numOfRows:9
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
numOfRows:6
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
numOfRows:3
(numOfSegments:3
.current_process:<function current_process at 0x0000017F7A4F1D80>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing from the parent process, not from a worker process.

To print from the worker process, you should put the print statement in the `run` method.
To uniqely identify a process, it is better to use `os.getpid()`.

Some style remarks;

- Instead of a for-loop with `map_async`, why not use a simple `map` (or `imap_unordered`)?
- The length of the variable names in combination with CamelCase makes the code hard to read.

**Edit2:**

> i tested the code on a single process and surprisingly, the processing time using single cpu is must faster the it using multi-cpus. any reason for that please?

Your question doesn't contain enough information to be sure. What follows is my best guess.

There is an amount of overhead associated with `multiprocessing`. Think about this: All the data that you sumbit to `apply_async` in `args` has to be packaged (using `pickle`) and sent to the worker processes via interprocess communication and unpackaged. *The same goes for any data returned by the workers!*
If the amount of data is large, the time for that needed could overwhelm the time needed for the execution of the `run` method.

If large amounts of data have to be sent to or received from workers, I would recommend writing that data to a file on an SSD or RAM-disk, and send the workers merely the *name* of the input file. Similarly the workers should only return the (random!) name of any output file.

*Hint*: You can use the `cProfile` module to get an idea about where your programs are spending there time. On my website I've published several articles about profiling Python programs. [Here](https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/programming/profiling-python-scripts-1-stl2pov.html) is the start of that series. If you want to improve program performance, you should *always start with profiling*.

Comment: thanks, would you please tell me why map is preferred over map_async?

Comment: thanks for the info, i fixed the bug, anyway, it was already fixed in my original code. it maybe it appeared in the code i posted for this question due to the incorrect indentation

Comment: do you think i started new process correctly? i tested the code on a single process and surprisingly, the processing time using single cpu is must faster the it using multi-cpus..any reason for that please?

Comment: See **Edit2** in my updated answer.

Comment: I did not yet read your answer completely, but I am using map-async not apply-async

Comment: Oh, I must have misread. Removed **Edit1**.